# Extract html table row to google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I’m trying to extract a single row from a table

When using the google sheet importhtml function, I get the whole table.

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/jwn/options?mod=mw_quote_tab", "table",1)
```

How can I extract just the row right above the word  “ Current price as of “

So e.g. in this case the row will have the data below. (this data will change as the date changes)

quote   1.5 0.53    76  1.36    1.47    142 39  quote   0.88    -1.73   23

I have several urls to go thorough

So e.g if I put the following url then the row position will change.

https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ge/options

Any idea how to extract that just last row right above the word “ Current price as of “

Comment: ImportHTML() lets you to read an (entire!) HTML table or list into your Google sheet.  It isn't intended for anything more granular than that.  If you want to do further manipulation or filtering of your Google sheet.... then you get to use one of the Google Sheets APIs.  See my response below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I saw the HTML data from the URL of `https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ge/options`, I thought that the value you expect might be able to be retrieved using `IMPORTXML` and a xpath. So in this answer, I would like to propose to use `IMPORTXML`.

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr[td[1]/@class='acenter inthemoney'][last()]")
```

- In this case, the URL of `https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ge/options` is put in the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample formula can be used for the current URL of `https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/ge/options`. So when the URL is changed and the HTML structure is changed by updated of the site, the formula might not be able to be used. So please careful this.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: Clever workaround. But the OP needs to learn a bit of [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp) syntax.  Certainly a Good Thing.  Just like learning about [Google Sheets functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273) is also a Good Thing...

Comment: Hi Tanaike, that code worked, Thanks for your help.  With this pulling of the data it will give me some sort of an idea how xml works, once again Thanks for your time and figuring this out.!!

Comment: Hello Tanaike, for some reason it worked for a while and now i don't get any data from the site something wrong and something got changed, i was wondering if you can let me know what seems to be the problem. I still have my google sheet to create the link for it. Thanks.!

Comment: @don About your comment, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have already said `when the URL is changed and the HTML structure is changed by updated of the site, the formula might not be able to be used. So please careful this.` at "Note" section. It is considered that the reason of your current is is due to this. I deeply apologize for this. And, about your current situation, I cannot understand about the values you expect. Can you update your question by including the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Yeah, i understood that site will change things and once things are changed it will not work, you mentioned that in your reply first time and i appreciate it. I was wondering if you can look at and see what got changed and adjust it for me, i will really appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: @don Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I asked that about your current situation, I cannot understand about the values you expect and can you update your question by including the detail of your current issue and your goal? But, from your replying, I cannot understand about your current situation. By this, I cannot think of it. I deeply apologize for this. By the way, in this case, when the HTML structure was changed in the future, even when your new issue was resolved, should I continue to resolve your issue in the future? I'm worry about this.

Comment: Just thought you understood my problem and solved it the first time, so you might be able to fix the minor change to it, i will close it out this thread and will post it again. Thanks.

Comment: @don Thank you for replying. About your new post, I would like to support you. I would like to check it.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, i posted at the following post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67428289/extract-a-single-row-from-a-table?noredirect=1#comment119186101_67428289

Comment: @don Thank you for your response. I will check it. When I found the solution, I would like to answer it.

Answer (score -1):

- ImportHTML() simply allows you to read an (entire!) HTML table or list into your Google sheet.
- If you want to filter or manipulate the imported data, then you'll need to use other Google Sheets functions. These are documented here:

  [Google Sheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273)
- Alternatively, you might want to "import" input one sheet, then select certain data into another, separate sheet:

  [Get data from other sheets in your spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943)
- Here are some examples for "filtering" your data:

  [FILTER function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem though :(, in time i will learn those, seems complicated, any idea how to simply solve the problem that i mentioned. Thanks.