# Extract a single row from a table

Tags: html, xml

I’m trying to extract a single row from a table.

I'm using google sheet to create the links and in cell D3 it contains this url.

https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/AAPL/options

I have several links in cell D3 to go through.

The word "Last Trade" appears several times in different tables but I'M ONLY INTERESTED IN THE VERY FIRST TABLE FROM THE TOP.
with this word and once this word is found i'm looking to extract the ROW just above it.

Below is the IMPORTXML, and its needs modification and it should be able to pull that last row.

=IMPORTXML(D3,"//tr[td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3sm9.png)/@class='acenter inthemoney'][last()]")

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: 1. When I open the link(https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/AAPL/options), I don't see your used @class="acenter inthemoney". I only see @class="inthemoney". 2. Your statement about "Below is the IMPORTXML, and its needs modification and it should be able to pull that last row." is in contrast with  the paragraph above it. Can you explain?

Comment: I don’t know much about XML coding, and the main objective is to get the last row of data, I had posted this question before and one of the person responded and gave me that code and it was working on the following web site.
https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/AAPL/options

Something got changed and now its not working, so either site will work as long as I can get that last row right above CURRENT PRICES AS OF in the marketwatch site OR the row above LASTRADE in WSJ site.   Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask you about the output values you expect?

Comment: so on WSJ site, right above the word LAST TRADE 130.21 THE ROW which contains this data so just need this row.   0.28 -0.17 0.11 0.28 146189 61499 130.00 0.02 -0.98  0.01 61801 15529

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `so on WSJ site, right above the word LAST TRADE 130.21 THE ROW which contains this data so just need this row. 0.28 -0.17 0.11 0.28 146189 61499 130.00 0.02 -0.98 0.01 61801 15529`, I cannot still understand about the values you expect. Could you please explain it using an image? By this, I would like to try to understand it. By the way, when you reply to the comment, when you add `@` to the user name like `@Tanaike`, the user can notice your reply comment.

Comment: @Tanaike Hello Tanaike, seems like the other person that thought he has a solution couldn't resolve it and i was wondering if you can take a look at this problem and let me know how to get it fix. Thanks.!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `seems like the other person that thought he has a solution couldn't resolve it and i was wondering if you can take a look at this problem and let me know how to get it fix.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your replying, unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your expected values. But I would like to try to understand about your question. When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

For that row you will need:

```
(//tr[@class='last_trade_row'])[1]/preceding-sibling::tr[1]
```

And then pick the wright td...it's unclear which td you want. So if you wanted the third td the XPath would be:

```
(//tr[@class='last_trade_row'])[1]/preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td[3]
```

Its always the first table that ends with the word LAST TRADE and the row above it that i'm looking to extract, so in this case this is the row that i'm looking to extract, below is the picture.

https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/AAPL/options

[image]

In the above case where you want the first td the XPath will then be

```
 (//tr[@class='last_trade_row'])[1]/preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]
```

Comment: (//tr[@class='last_trade_row'])[1]/preceding-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]   Its not working, something is missing.